# Source of Greg LeMond's quote, "It never gets easier; you just go faster."

Tags: quote-source, greg-lemond

I'm writing an article about cycling and I want to include a well know quote from the professional cyclist Greg LeMond (the first and only American to win the Tour de France).  The quote is:

> It never gets easier, you just get faster.

This quote is widely used, but I'm having trouble finding the original source.  I would like to properly attribute it in my citations.  For example in the book about LeMond's '89 Tour win, The Comeback by Daniel de Visé, the author uses the quote as the opening epigraph.  The Comeback includes an extensive notes section where Visé attributes his sources, but I don't see any source for the LeMond quote.  Many other books about cycling use this quote too, but likewise don't include the original source.

This quote shows up all over the Internet too.  For example the web site [Velominati](https://www.velominati.com/) uses LeMond's quote for their tenth rule without attributing the source.  Also consistent with how the quote is used the wording varies.  The version used by the Velominati substitues *go* for *get*:

> It never gets easier, you just go faster.

Anyone know where this quote originated?